# Selecting elements from DOM

Tags: dom, css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

On my page contents, I have multiple cards organized as a grid

```
 __________________
|  ____    ____    |
| |    |  |    |   |
| |    |  |    |   |
| |____|  |____|   |
|                  |
|  ____    ____    |
| |    |  |    |   |
| |    |  |    |   |
| |____|  |____|   |
|__________________|
```

My issue is that each card container has the same class, and I want to select a distinct element inside a container. Example:

```
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="container">
    <h2> Distinct title 1 </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="another-container">
      <button>
        <span> Click Here! </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

[repeat X times]
```

or using a DOM tree

```
. Parent div
|_ child div
|  |_ <h2> Distinct title 3 </h2>
|
|_ child div
   |_ grandchild div
      |_ button
         |_ <span> Click Here! </span>
```

So, supposedly I want to select an element on the third container. How would the selector query be?

Based on @lostlemon answer, my query is the following:

```
await t
  .click(Selector('span')
  .parent(3)
  .child('h2')
  .withExactText('Distinct title 3'));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you *always* want to select the third container in this scenario, you could use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type`:

```
await t.click('div:nth-child(3) > span');
```

If you need to click on the span based on title, try this:

```
await t
    .click(Selector('span').parent('.parent-container')
    .child('h2').withExactText('Distinct title 3');
```

- `.withText()` can be removed if all the `<span>`s have the same text
- make sure your parent selector is trying to find the class and not an element if you're targeting the container class
- `.find()` looks for an element, so it wouldn't match the distinct title text

Comment: I edited the example DOM. Basically, my test needs to read the `<h2>` header, go up, and then click on the `<span>` that is a sibling of the `<h2>` header

Comment: gotcha, updated the answer. I noticed in particular your `.parent('container')` was missing the period at the start for class

Comment: got it. Basically, I can navigate through the DOM using the `parent` and `child` relationships. So, my DOM has some more levels (updated the question again), but my query is trying to click at the `<h2>` title, not the button

Comment: I still cannot click the right element based on my updated query. Could you give me a hand please?

Comment: Does reordering the selector chains work? i.e. `.click(Selector('h2').withExactText('Distinct title 3').parent('.parent-container').child('span'));` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just give each span a unique class.

```
<span class="card-1">CONTENT</span>
```

Comment: the classes are auto generated, I cannot control

Comment: Is it being generated through JS? I know with jQuery you can add html into new elements that are created.

Comment: The page uses React