# Print current DOM element

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to select an element based on a sibling element, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54910527/selecting-elements-from-dom). However, I get an error `The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.` which means that testcafe didn't find my element.

To help debug, it would be good if I could print the DOM element currently being read by `Selector()`.

Using `console.log(Selector('element'))` prints out the object. Is there a way to output the current DOM element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can output any property of [DOM Node Snapshot](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html).

For example

```js
console.log(await Selector('element').innerText);
console.log(await Selector('element').value);
```